# EPSG:31254 to WGS84 Transformation Parameters

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, epsg

The official transformation parameters from EPSG:31254 to WGS84 are:

> towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 (EPSG:1618)

(defined [here](http://www.bev.gv.at/pls/portal/url/ITEM/38A4FDFE4CD57DBBE040010A83215AF0) and used by ArcGIS MGI_To_WGS_1984_3 transformation method as well as in the EPSG:31254 definition used by QGis 2.18.1)

**GeoServer 2.11.0** on the other hand uses the following transformation parameters in its EPSG:31254 definition:

> TOWGS84[601.705, 84.263, 485.227, 4.7354, -1.3145, -5.393, -2.3887].

If I provide GeoServer with an alternate version of EPSG:31254 by using the epsg_overrides.properties file - using the EPSG:1618 transformation parameters -  the layer is displayed in the wrong position (way off).

**Question:**

Why does GeoServer use these transformation parameters and not the official ones, and where does it get them from?

Why don't the official parameters work with GeoServer?

Comment: GeoServer gets it's projections from the official EPSG database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values taken by Geoserver are valid only for Steiermark: http://epsg.io/1024

All other PROJ/GDAL based software uses the countrywide values: http://epsg.io/1618

Note that the first uses `Coordinate Frame Rotation`, while the second uses `Position Vector Transformation`. The difference is in the sign of the rotation and scale parameter values (4 to 7).